# Directory not notified as modified when a file is deleted

Tags: watchman

Using watchman 4.9.0 with inotify.

I am subscribed as `'subscribe', '/home/meta', 'Buffy', {"expression": ["since", "c:1517100837:2861:1:1"],
"fields": ["name", "exists", "oclock", "ctime_ns", "new", "mode"]}`.

When I create a new file in the directory, I get a notification with two entries: one indicates that the directory changed and the other indicates that a new file is available.

**PS:**. I am talking about creating a file inside a directory inside the root dir. That is, I am monitoring `/home/meta`, I have a directory `/home/meta/test` and I create a file `/home/meta/test/z`. If the file is created inside the "root" dir, I don't get any notification at all about the directory.

When I delete that file, I only get a "exists:false" notification about the deleted file, but I don't see any notification about a change in the directory.

This is important because I am migrating a legacy application to watchman and I am actually observing only directory changes. When a directory changes, I do a "since" request to it to learn about the actual changes. This is not working on deletes.

Suggestions?

Thanks!.

Comment: does this still manifest after making the changes I suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48493592/149111 ?  If so, please open an issue on the github tracker; we monitor that much actively than stackoverflow

Comment: After correcting that issue, I don't see directories updates at all when creating/deleting files. Is that intended?. Could be possible to add a flag to request those updates too? Should I move this to github now? :)

Comment: Please file an issue on github, because this sounds like a bug and we can track and discuss it more effectively over on github.  Thanks!

Comment: Bug filled: https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/566 . Thanks!