# watchman: I am missing file deletions happening before subscription

Tags: watchman

I am missing deletes in watchman. Version 4.9.0, inotify.

My test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pathlib
import pywatchman

w = pywatchman.client()

w.query('watch', '/tmp/z')
clock = w.query('clock', '/tmp/z')['clock']
print(clock)

q = w.query('subscribe', '/tmp/z', 'Buffy', {'expression':["since", clock],
"fields": ["name", "exists", "oclock", "ctime_ns", "new", "mode"]})
print(q)

f = pathlib.Path('/tmp/z/xx')

f.touch()
data = w.receive()
clock = data['clock']
print()
print('Touch file:')
print(data)
print('Clock:', clock)

f.unlink()
print()
print('Delete file:')
print(w.receive())
w.close()

w = pywatchman.client(timeout=99999)
q = w.query('subscribe', '/tmp/z', 'Buffy', {'expression':["since", clock],
"fields": ["name", "exists", "oclock", "ctime_ns", "new", "mode"]})
print(q)

print()
print('We request changes since', clock)
print(w.receive())
w.close()
```

What I am seeing:

1. We create the file. We receive the notification of the new file and the directory change. **GOOD**. We take note of the "clock" of this notification.
2. We delete the file. We get the notification of the file deletion. **GOOD**. Be DO NOT get the notification of the directory change.

Just imagine now that the process crashes BEFORE it can update the internal details, but it remember the changes notified in step 1 (directory update and creation of a new file). That is, transaction 1 is processed, but the program crashes before transaction 2 is processed.

3. We now open a new subscription to watchman (remember, we are simulating a crash) and request changes since step 1. I am simulating a recovery, where the program reboots, notice that transaction 1 was OK (the file is present) and request more changes (it should get the deletion).
4. I would expect to get a file deletion but I get... NOTHING. **CATASTROPHIC**.

Transcript:

```
$ ./watchman-bug.py 
c:1517109517:10868:3:23
{'clock': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:23', 'subscribe': 'Buffy', 'version': '4.9.0'}

Touch file:
{'unilateral': True, 'subscription': 'Buffy', 'root': '/tmp/z', 'files': [{'name': 'xx', 'exists': True, 'oclock': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:24', 'ctime_ns': 1517114230070245747, 'new': True, 'mode': 33188}], 'is_fresh_instance': False, 'version': '4.9.0', 'since': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:23', 'clock': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:24'}
Clock: c:1517109517:10868:3:24

Delete file:
{'unilateral': True, 'subscription': 'Buffy', 'root': '/tmp/z', 'files': [{'name': 'xx', 'exists': False, 'oclock': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:25', 'ctime_ns': 1517114230070245747, 'new': False, 'mode': 33188}], 'is_fresh_instance': False, 'version': '4.9.0', 'since': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:24', 'clock': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:25'}
{'clock': 'c:1517109517:10868:3:25', 'subscribe': 'Buffy', 'version': '4.9.0'}

We request changes since c:1517109517:10868:3:24
```

The process hangs expecting the deletion notification.

What am I doing wrong?.

Thanks for your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a `since` expression term rather than informing watchman to use the `since` generator (the recency index).

What's the difference?  You can think of this as the difference between the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses in SQL.  The `expression` field is similar in intent to the `WHERE` clause: it applies to the matched results and filters them down, but what you wanted to do is specify the `FROM` clause by setting the `since` field in the query spec.  This is admittedly a subtle difference.

The solution is to remove the expression term and add the generator term like this:

```
q = w.query('subscribe', '/tmp/z', 'Buffy', 
            {"since": clock,
             "fields": ["name", "exists", "oclock",
                        "ctime_ns", "new", "mode"]})
```

While we don't have really any documentation on the use of the pywatchman API, you can borrow the concepts from the slightly better documented nodejs API; here's a relevant snippet:

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/nodejs.html#subscribing-only-to-changed-files

Comment: Oh, Thanks. It works!. Please, improve documentation. Navigation is really painful and some examples and use cases would be really welcomed. Interestingly, with this change I don't see directory updates when files are created/deleted.

Comment: Forget the comment about the directory updates. I will try to get a reproducible testcase to file a bug.