# watchman: precise meaning and handling of "is_fresh_instance"

Tags: watchman

So far I have considered "is_fresh_instance" as "I don't know about previous history, so I send you all data again". This works fine when my "since" is "0" or similar. I get everything and I interpret "is_fresh_instance" as a signal that this is not an incremental update but a full dump.

But I am seeing this today.

I am monitoring a tree with more than 200 directories and 12.000 files in there. I create a new file inside. My file monitor is offline (watchman process is running but nobody is subscribed). I launch my file monitor and it requests an "incremental" dump with "since". I get this:

```
{'unilateral': True, 'subscription': 'Buffy', 'root': '/home/meta', 'is_fresh_instance': True, 'version': '4.9.0', 'clock': 'c:1517109517:10868:2:97', 'files': [{'name': 'dir', 'exists': True, 'oclock': 'c:1517109517:10868:2:97', 'ctime_ns': 1517168825691348944, 'new': True, 'mode': 16877}, {'name': 'dir/FILE.TXT', 'exists': True, 'oclock': 'c:1517109517:10868:2:97', 'ctime_ns': 1517168825787349000, 'new': True, 'mode': 33188}]}
```

Here I am getting "is_fresh_instance=True" but I get an incremental notification. How to proceed?. Directory "dir" is signaled as "new" (it is NOT) and then I guess I should do a "query" to request the content, but then I don't understand why I get the notification of the new file if I am supposed to scan the directory anyway because it is "new" (it is not).

I find watchman semantics to be really confused. Documentation navigation is awful and I don't see any example I can study.

What is watchman expecting me to do when I get "is_fresh_instance=True"?

This case is 100% reproducible. If I create the file while a subscription is in course, I see "is_fresh_instance=False". If my monitor is offline and when it comes back it requests a "since" with an up to date clock, I get the same notification (directory and file) but with "is_fresh_instance=True".

Help!. Python code examples?.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that some of your issues are related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48493592/149111 but you are dead right that our documentation could be better, so here's some background information.

### What is a fresh instance result?

A fresh instance result is generated by watchman when it cannot tell you about events that happened in the time frame you requested.  There are a few situations that can trigger this:

- The watchman server was restarted since your last query
- The watch was cancelled and restarted.
- The system was unable to keep up with the rate of change of watched files and the kernel flushed the queue to keep up. (we call this a *recrawl* because we have to re-examine the watched tree)
- You're using timestamps rather than clocks and the timestamp is out of range of known events.
- You're using a [named cursor](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/clockspec.html) and that name has not been used before.
- You're using a blank clock string for the `since` generator in a query (this is not the same thing as a `since` term in a query expression!)

### What does a fresh instance result mean?

Watchman wants to make sure that you cannot miss the events that are interesting to you, so it it is ever wrong or misses something, it will tell you about everything, just in case.

The `is_fresh_instance` flag is set in these situations and it means that it is telling you about everything that exists and matches at the time of your query.

### What are you supposed to do about it?

If you have any cached information about the filesystem from prior watchman queries, you *must* discard it because it is now stale.  The results from watchman include information about all of the files that currently exist.  This is an important signal to help prevent stateful consumers of watchman data from diverging from the view of the world.  The problematic scenario that this prevents is this:

- File `A` existed and showed up in a prior query result, and you cached that information
- watchman stops
- File `A` is deleted
- watchman starts

If you don't purge your cache you may falsely believe that `A` still exists based on its presence in your cached state.

If you don't have any cached information then you needn't do anything different and you can ignore the flag.

### What if I don't want the list of all files?

For some consumers, especially those with extremely large trees, it may be desirable to perform some other application defined fallback processing if you encounter a fresh instance result set.

You may set `empty_on_fresh_instance: true` in your query to tell watchman to give you an empty `files: []` list instead of information about all current files.

If you decide to use this flag, I'd recommend that you follow up with a watchman query `since` the `clock` returned in the `is_fresh_instance` query result to make sure that you haven't missed any additional changes that may have happened during your fallback processing.

In general, I do not recommend using this flag unless you are really sure that you need it.

### Where can I find some python examples?

We don't have a lot of educational examples in python, but there are some real programs you can look at:

- [watchman-make](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/python/bin/watchman-make) - uses subscriptions to trigger a build
- [watchman-wait](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/python/bin/watchman-wait) - like the inotifywait tool
- the [mercurial fsmonitor extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/hgext/fsmonitor); most of the watchman specific code is in [**init**.py](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/hgext/fsmonitor/__init__.py).  This code uses a polling model because it is not a long lived process.  fsmonitor maintains a cache so it is important for it to process fresh instance results correctly, or else weird things start to happen to the contents of commits in the repo!